# Easy way to convert one row of data into multiple in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet that looks like this:

[image]

Right now each **Number** contains a varying amount of **Companies** and **Company Numbers**.  I would like to set up the spreadsheet so each **Company** has their own row for each **Number**.  See below for visual representation.

I would like to convert the spreadsheet for each existing row like this:

[image]

So row 2 would be converted into row 2 and row 3 to look like this:

[image]

There are thousands of rows already so doing this manually would be quite the pain.  Is there a way to use Excel functionality to convert the spreadsheet to fit this?

Comment: You could do this with several sets of functions on to a new worksheet. However, is VBA an acceptable solution? If so, you could have something loop through every row, count how many companies are to the right, insert that many rows, and move the companies from the right into those new rows.

Comment: A solution like that should work for me.  I have little experience with VBA, so would need, at the very least, some pseudo code on what this would look like.  Even better if someone could write something out in VBA.